# Is there a reason to install the MonoTouch environment on Windows if the iOS simulator only runs on OS X?

Tags: ide, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

Given that the iOS emulator only runs on OS X, what are reasons that people do MonoTouch development on Windows?  They offer MonoDevelop for both Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of only being able to place an app using ONLY the mac tools is not ENTIRELY correct. You are completely able to use the iTunes connect website https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/4.0.0.7.3.0.9.3.1.1 to place apps on the app store, and you only need the xcode tool for stuff like using the simulator and other options such as that. The reason why people do things such as program on a Windows is because some people are more native with the way the UI works on Windows than on a Mac, as they are quite different. The Windows is more visual, and it offers a simple way to get to things; although the Mac is more user friendly when it comes to the way applications are handled in the core of them. Also, people don't always want to pay the 1200+ price for a Mac machine, when yet they can spend 200+ on a simple Windows OS machine, and still possess the same kind of options. Another thing, you can always run Windows through a mac, so it's kind of a positive negative situation in almost any circumstance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps a lot.  I am going to correct my question to remove the incorrect statement about having to deploy through OS X.

Comment: glad I could help you! I have wondered that about many different applications, but after using multiple ide's for both mac and windows, I understand the reason for deciding to use one over the over. Just as with Java, I prefer to use Java on a windows machine than on a mac because it is more readable to me, but I prefer to do c/c++/objective-c on a Mac because of the way Xcode works and is set up! So it just really all depends on the preferences of the programmer I guess. :)

Comment: You still have to have a Mac to build, test and deploy to a device.  You may be able to actually upload your code from any browser, but building for distribution requires a Mac, even when using Xamarin tools.  So the cost savings is somewhat moot when specifically talking about Xamarin.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, you must have that for a device. However, if you have a best friend who owns a Mac, and they don't really use it or they allow you to borrow it for use with the deployment and other options, it would be seen as a sort of costly thing to go out and buy a Mac, when you can use the same tools, and just use the mac you borrow to build and distribute, but that's my opinion. :)

Answer (score 4):

Some people prefer Visual Studio.  Some teams may have invested in tools (like ReSharper, etc) that run in Visual Studio.  And teams that maintain other .NET projects may not to switch to Macs as their primary environment.

Comment: so they develop in Windows and then run the code in the simulator on iOS?  I guess once you get a process and automate it it's doable.

Comment: it uses a Mac as a build server when you run it under Windows.  Running the Visual Studio edition also requires a more expensive Xamarin license than the Mac only version.

Answer (score 1):

My personal reasons for using Visual Studio currently for my iOS development are:

1. I'm doing mixed-client-and-server development, and have a single solution with several project types which Xamarin Studio doesn't yet support - or which it only partially supports:

   - Portable Class Libraries
   - Azure website projects
   - WindowsPhone projects
   - WindowsStore projects
2. Resharper and the Visual Studio productivity tools and are key parts of my toolchain - they really do make me more productive. (There are other tools too which I'm more familiar with on the PC - e.g. even things like notepad++ and Paint.Net)
3. Because of my last 20 years on Windows I'm faster at working on the PC - although I am getting quicker at using the Mac.